# Difference between for and foreach loop Container in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

What is the difference between `for` and `foreach` loop Container  in `SSIS`

Comment: Why was this downvoted? it's the first google result for this exact question...

Answer (score 9):

A for loop will execute the tasks a specified number of times, in other words 10 times, or 25 times, and the number of times is specified in the definition of the container. You can use a variable to specify what that count is.

A for each loop will execute once for each item in the collection of items that it is looking at. A good example would be if users are putting an Excel file into a directory for import into the DB. You cannot tell ahead of time how many will be in the directory, because a user might be late, or there might be more than one file from a given user. When you define the ForEach container, yoou would tell it to execute for each *.xls in the directory, and it will then loop through, importing each one individually, regardless of how many files are actually there.